# If $A$ is in $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$, then is $A=-A^*$ diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

If $A$ is in $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$, then is $A=-A^*$ diagonalizable?

Comment: Not necessarily over the reals. For example, try and see what happens if $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. (I'm assuming $A^*$ is the adjoint, which is just the transpose in the real case.)

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Surely *not* over the reals, unless $A=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A = -A^*$, then $A$ is normal:
$$A A^* = A (-A) = (-A) A = A^* A .$$
In particular, $A$ is diagonalizable (in fact, unitarily diagonalizable) over $\Bbb C$.

The condition $A = -A^*$ implies that the eigenvalues of $\lambda$ are imaginary, however, so a matrix $A$ satisfying it is diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$ iff all of the eigenvalues are zero, that is, iff $A = 0$.